# Error while trying to use pdf2image on heroku : libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, heroku

I get the Exception:
`pdfinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

on the line
`images = pdf2image.convert_from_path("filename.pdf")`

I tried adding [this buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/freddix/libpng12), but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had the same issue and solved it as follows:

1. Remove the libpng buildback and the poppler utils buildback
2. Create an `Aptfile` in the root directory of your project and add `libpng-dev` and `poppler-utils` to the file
3. Add the official heroku api buildback `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt`
4. Push a new version of your app to Heroku.